# How to reset the Windows Push Notification Platform?

Tags: windows-8, notifications, windows-store-app, live-tiles

For my user account, the  Windows Push Notification Platform seems to be messed up. I have the following symptoms:

- In the `Settings` charm, `Notifications` is grayed out. The tool-tip is `Turned off by Group Policy`.
- Visual Studio fails to install an app that is capable of toasts and live tiles with the following error:

  `Error  1   Error : DEP0700 : Registration of the app failed. error 0x80072EE4: The Visual Elements extension failed while processing the Notification element. (0x80073cf6)    MenSaar`

  The event log `Microsoft/Windows/Microsoft-Windows-AppXDeploymentServer/Operational` contains many related entries, the most relevant of which appears to be the following:

  `error 0x80073CF6: AppX Deployment operation failed. The specific error text for this failure is: error 0x80072EE4: The Visual Elements extension failed while processing the Notification element.`
- The same app fails to install from the Windows Store.
- The event log `Microsoft/Windows/PushNotifications-Platform/Operational` contains many of the following entries:

  `The Windows Push Notification Platform has encountered an error in file: base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\endpoint\platform.cpp, function NotificationPlatform::Initialize, line 595: 0x80072EE4.`

  `The Windows Push Notification Platform has encountered an error in file: base\diagnosis\platform\notifications\platform\ui\cachemanager.cpp, function CacheManager::Initialize, line 170: 0x80072EE4.`
- The event log `Microsoft/Windows/Microsoft-Windows-TWinUI/Operational` contains many of the following entries:

  `The Windows Notification platform has failed initialization.  Notifications will not work until after a restart.`
- My Notifications settings are in the following state:

  [image: screenshot of settings]

  Usually, this is impossible: The latter options are only grayed out if the first option is disabled. I can un-gray the latter options by disabling and re-enabling the first option, but this does not persist.

These issues are local to my account (at least the first one, I haven't carefully tested all of them).

By resetting that part to the profile to the default profile, I verified that `~\AppData\Local\` is *not* the (only) cause of the problem.

Windows logs this error to `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\TileNotifications\`. While writing the registry entry, `explorer.exe` has the following stack:

[image: captured stack]

**How can I reset the Windows Push Notification Platform? What else could I do to remedy this?**

Answer (score 0):

The hard way: Surrender your profile.

Copy your profile to a safe place, delete & re-create your account, log in once, copy back all data except for the `Microsoft` folders in `AppData\Local` and `AppData\Roaming` and the Registry. Only copy back the remaining stuff on a one-by-one basis, carefully checking whether you broke something and rolling back in case you did.

*This solved the problem for me for now, but for future reference, I'm still looking for an answer.*

Answer (score 0):

Find and delete this registry key and reboot

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PushNotifications]
"NoToastApplicationNotification"=dword:00000001
"NoCloudApplicationNotification"=dword:00000001
"NoTileApplicationNotification"=dword:00000001
```